# Angular 4 - Propagate Selection Up in PrimeNG Tree not working

Tags: angular, primeng

The **propagateSelectionUp** setting is not selecting the above node / parent when data is populated from a json file. There is a property "parent" of typ TreeNode, but i'm not sure how to add that in the json file.

I have printed the node object to the console to be able to discover methods and properties, and saw that the "node.parent" is undefined... is there a method for setting the parent?

```
<p-tree [value]="filesTree11" layout="horizontal" selectionMode="checkbox" [(selection)]="selectedFile3" [propagateSelectionUp]="true" [propagateSelectionDown]="false" (click)="test()"></p-tree>
```

Comment: If you remove `layout="horizontal"` do you still have the problem ?

Comment: @Antikhippe Then it works better, it auto-selects the closest parent, and i get a tick all the way to the root node

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks for the downvote. What's wrong with the tags?

Comment: @BakedInhalf so I think it is not implemented with horizontal layout...

Comment: @Antikhippe Ok, then I guess I have to create a function in js that does that for me..

Comment: Yes, and you can also inform PrimeNG team if you want.

Comment: @Kukeltje Yes, they are perfect. Question is related to PrimeNG, and if it's not implemented in Prime, I must create my own function using Angular, hence the tags.

Comment: @Kukeltje I thought PrimeNG was a part of Primefaces... Happy now?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I already suggested multiple times to the prime-ng team to put all the primeng stuff on a new url

Comment: @Antikhippe Ok. Will try to write the code in js.

Comment: @Kukeltje So regarding the question, do you have any ideas on this? I'm guessing something similar to "expandRecursive", but the other way around.. The problem is that the UI doesnt use the parent property

Comment: Sorry, I don't use PrImeNG, I use PrimeFaces so I have no idea...

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into the `node.parent == null` issue with `layout="horizontal"` today. I don't think it's intended to be that way.

Probably you've got your own way around it by now. If not (or whoever might need it later): Here are two ways of setting the parent-node:

1. **Quick-n-dirty**: You could insert another tree-component into your `.html` file which acesses the same nodes as your horizontal tree. Then hide it using `style`:

   `<p-tree> [value]="filesTree11" [style]="{'display': 'none'}"</p-tree>`.

   This said, it's an ugly and certainly not permanent solution. But for proof-of-concept or testing I don't see why not...
2. **The thorough approach**: Iterate and set the parent property recursively through the nodes just after assigning the json data to `filesTree11` by calling `this.processTreeNodes(filesTree11, null)`:

   ```
   private processTreeNodes(treeNode: TreeNode[], parent: TreeNode) {
       for (const node of treeNode) {
           if (parent != null) {
               node.parent = parent;
           }
           if (node.children.length > 0) {
               this.processTreeNodes(node.children, node);
        }
   }
   ```

   To verify if `node.parent` has been set, you could call this function after the one above:

   ```
   private checkTreeNodes(treeNode: TreeNode[]) {
     for (const node of treeNode) {
       node.parent != null ?
           console.log('>> ' + node.parent.label + ' > ' + node.label) :
           console.log('>> ' + 'null');
       if (node.children.length > 0) {
         this.checkTreeNodes(node.children);
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   The "manual" approach has the advantage of letting you set a couple of additional properties, like `expanded`, `data`, `type`, ...

Comment: Yes I did something similar as your 2nd approach. Nice one! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using the `p-tree` horizontally. The quickest way I found to solve the problem is to store the reference to the parent node in the `data` property of the node

```ts
private buildTreeNode(..., parent?: TreeNode): TreeNode  {
  // Do stuff
  const node = {
    // ... set your node properties here
    data: {
      // Your other data stuff goes here
      parent: parent, /*<-- THIS SAVES ME THE DAY*/
    }
  } as TreeNode;
  // Do other stuff
  return node;
}
```

And then use it to navigate backwards

```ts
// Assume onDelete is called from HTML and the deleted element is passed as parameter
onDelete(node: TreeNode): void {
  if (node.data.parent) {
    const index = node.data.parent.children?.indexOf(node);
    if (index !== undefined) {
      node.data.parent.children?.splice(index, 1);
    }
  } else {
    // You deleted the root node
  }
}
```